# Увеличить значение в xml на 1

Tags: cmd, bat

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<provider>
    <id version="8">blbla_desk</id>
    <name>namedesk</name>
    ....

</provider>
```

Как в xml файле заменить значение id version на 1 больше, например текущее значение 8, то будет 9. если 20 то 21.

Comment: Вам нужен xmlstarlet. Это утилита командной строки которая может сделать с xml все что угодно.

Comment: Открыть в текстовом редакторе, изменить, сохранить. Вопрос не содержит достаточно информации о том какие у вас обстоятельства для решения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Вот код для вывода нужной сформированной строки.
А уж как запихать её в файл - задача много проще.

```
@echo off
call :num "<provider>"

setlocal  enabledelayedexpansion         
for /f tokens^=1-3*^ delims^=^" %%a in ('more +%num% text.xml^|find/i"<id version="')do (
set /a val=%num%+1

@rem Вывод строки
@echo %%a"!val!"%%c

)
endlocal
goto :EOF

@rem Процедура поиска номера строки по параметру-шаблону
:num
for /f "delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /n %1 text.xml') do set num=%%a
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение на PHP:

```
<?php
$xmlString = '
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<provider>
    <id version="8">blbla_desk</id>
    <name>namedesk</name>
</provider>
';
$xmlString_clear = preg_replace("/<\?xml.*\?>/i", "", $xmlString);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlString_clear); 
echo $xml->id['version']+1;
?>
```